# Force the order of functions in the virtual method table?

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, data-structures, virtual

1. How can I control the order of virtual functions in the virtual table? Are they laid out in the same order that they are declared in?
2. When inheriting a class with a virtual table, is the virtual table of the inherited class an extension of the base class, or is an entirely new virtual table created with only the inherited classes virtual functions. (i.e. is the virtual table still at index +0x0 of the class?)

Comment: What are you trying to do where you would need this?

Comment: Implementation. Dependent.

Comment: I'm just trying to learn.
Dependent on what?

Comment: "Implementation dependent" means that a particular facet is not defined by the specification and its details are up to the implementation.  So it may change depending on what compiler (GNU, Microsoft, etc.) you use.

Comment: What Michael said. The standard just defines what version of the function is executed on a virtual function call. It's up to the compiler-writer to figure out how to implement and then optimize the required behaviour. Different C++ implementations therefore will have different details for this and other implementation-dependent areas. Sometimes for good reasons affecting performance or other measurable results, but sometimes for pretty arbitrary reasons that it's just how it happens to have been done in that compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. (a) As far as the standard is concerned, you can't, (in fact you can't even assume that vtables exist). (b) Probably, but what are the circumstances in which you need to control the order, but you can't check for yourself? The way to check is to look at the disassembly of a virtual call (and find the offset(s) added to the vtable pointer to get the call address) or to look at the disassembly of the vtable itself.
2. Depends. For single inheritance, probably it's an extension of the base class, and index 0 of each object points to a virtual table for the class, with pointer to the correct implementation (perhaps an override) for each virtual function declared in base classes, followed by pointers to each virtual function declared in the derived class. For multiple and virtual inheritance it isn't (can't be) that simple. Each object will contain several pointers, either to vtables or to structures which contain vtables plus other class information, and when you cast around the class hierarchy, the pointer value of the object changes. Try it and see.

All of this for a very hypothetical, "typical implementation". Compiler-writers have their tricks.

Answer (score 8):

That's completely implementation defined. The C++ standard does not specify any sort of a virtual function table at all -- that's just how it's typically implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual table is implementation specific. It may be laid out in any order. Even there may be no virtual table at all to implement polymorphism. I recommend **[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)** article on Wikipedia, which gives some answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

While certainly 100% true, the other answers ignore an obvious truth.

It's not a stupid question, depending on the posters goals. All too often, we're forced to use platform-specific technologies to achieve our goal. In particular, what the poster is trying to do is strikingly similar to COM on windows... writing pure virtual abstract interfaces that can be derived from are one of the few ways to get bulletproof C++ DLLs without dropping back down to a C interface.

I ran into the same issue while writing a plugin architecture in native C++ -- the lack of a ABI means that it is incredibly frustrating to interoperate.

Answer (score 0):

The question your question really begs is for what reason would you ever need to have the vtable in a particular order?

One of the reasons this is implementation dependent is because a compiler may make choices about how to layout the vtable for performance reasons, or other requirements, particular to a given CPU architecture.