# Does order of method declarations in a class matter to the compiler?

Tags: c++, function, class, declaration

I am using a third-party static library (.lib file) in a C++ project.  The author of the static library added a method to a class for me and sent me an updated build of the library.

Unfortunately, he didn't send a new header file and communication with him is slow, so I may not get the new header soon.  I know the method signature of the new method, so I could just add it to the header file.

My question is whether it matters where in the list of public methods I add the new declaration (top, bottom, middle...).  My best guess is that it *does* and that the order in the header file determines the order in the compiled class.  Can someone confirm or refute this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858914/does-the-function-declaration-order-matter-in-a-header-file

Comment: Please, have a look at [this stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858914/does-the-function-declaration-order-matter-in-a-header-file), which explains everything in details.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  The question you link to does help my understanding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My question is whether it matters where in the list of public methods I add the new declaration

AFAIK, it does not matter if the member function is regular function but it matters if it is a `virtual` member function. The virtual member functions in the virtual table are in a certain order. If the library has them in a different order than your .h file, you'll most likely end up calling the wrong function.

Related: [Force the order of functions in the virtual method table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225211/c-force-the-order-of-functions-in-the-virtual-method-table)

Comment: Wow, I hadn't thought of the issue with `virtual`s, but it seems to be a very real risk. The duplicates linked above mention it in passing, and the KDE link seems to go into proper depth on the ramifications from an ABI perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  In my case, the functions aren't virtual, so I'll just add the new method declaration at the bottom of the list and hope you're right :)

Comment: @adv12, I was bitten by the order of virtual tables a long time ago, in the early 2000s. If the member function is a regular member function, you should be ok. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If the method declaration does not uses types declared in the class as for example the return type then it is unimportant where the method is declared.

Otherwise if a method declaration depends on declarations of other types within the class then an error can occur.

For example the compiler will issue an error for this class definition

```
struct A
{
    B f();
    struct B {};
    //...
};
```

because type `struct B` is used in the member function declaration `f` before the structure declaration itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  In my case, the function is a `void something(CString)` (MFC string class) and doesn't use any types defined in the header.  So my concern was whether putting the method declaration in the "wrong" place in the class definition would make it so the wrong method got called.  But I forgot about the linker.  I'm most familiar with C#, where this sort of question doesn't come up.

Comment: @adv12 In this case there is no problem if the function declaration does not depend on other class members' declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Method declarations in a class shouldn't matter to the compiler, unless it depends on a variable declaration that hasn't been done yet.